# Show that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a countable union of open intervals.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

In the correction, they use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to prove it.

I was wondering if my approach was correct too :

Let $(a,b)$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}$

$\cup (a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ is a countable union of open sets causing $(a,b)$

I assume that I am wrong as this is very simple compared to what they do using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but I can't understand why my thing is wrong.

Edit: writing this I realized that this is not always true if $a$ and $b$ are close enough, but perhaps there always is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ where I can start the union for all $n>N$.

Comment: Not every open set is of the form $(a,b).$ If that were the case, there would be no argument needed since $(a,b)$ is manifestly the union countably many open intervals. (Namely it is the union of one open interval, itself.)

Comment: I see thank you

Comment: you are close though. can you write a set as a union of intervals?  maybe so that each endpoint is rational?

Comment: @CSquared It sounds like OP has already seen at least one standard proof, and was just questioning this alternate attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ be open set in $R$. We can write $O$ as union of open inteval (need not be countable union) $\bigcup_{i \in I} O_i$. First let us prove each $O_i$ is a countable union of open intervals. Note $O_i$ is of the form $(a,b)$ ($a$ and $b$ need not be finite). Note there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$ such that $a_n \to a$ (for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, this comes from density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and for $a = -\infty$, again by density, take a rational $q < b$ and set $a_n=q-n$). Similarly we can find $(b_n)$ in $\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$.

Now its clear that $O_i=(a,b)=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (a_j,b_j)$. To indicate the dependence on $i$ we rewrite the sequence $(a_n)$ as $(a_{n}^i)$ and $(b_n)$ as $(b_{n}^i)$. Note let $J_i = \{(a_{n}^{i},b_{n}^{i}) | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Note $\bigcup_{i \in I}J_i \subseteq (\mathbb{Q} \cup \{ -\infty , \infty \})^2$, so $J = \bigcup_{i \in I}J_i$ is countable.

Basic set theory tells us that:
$$O = \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{n =1}^{\infty}(a_{n}^{i},b_{n}^{i}) = \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{X \in J_i}X=\bigcup_{X \in J}X $$
It is a nice exercise to verify the last equality.

Thus, $O$ is a union of countably many open intervals.

Comment: Just to clarify, any occurence of $(a_{n}^i,b_{n}^{i})$ is a open interval not an ordered pair